# How to pass Form1 value to Form3 in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, return-value

How to pass value of *form1* directly to *Form3*.

In *Form1* i have **button** and a `Textbox` named **txtUsername** .

```
   public string username = string.Empty;
 private void LoginBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         username = txtUsername.Text;
         Form3 form  = new Form3(username);

         Form2 frm = new Form2();
         frm.Show();
         this.Hide
}
```

and in *From2* i have this

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
            Form3 form = new Form3();
            form.Show();
            this.Hide();
       }
```

and in *Form3*

```
public string Name;
        public Form3(string CName)
                {

                    InitializeComponent();
                    Name= Cname;
                }

private void frmTicketandCottages_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
      MessageBox.Show(Name); 
         }
```

to display the text.

But when i display the text i only get an Empty Text

Any other method to do this ?

Comment: please verify you really have any value us `username` variable

Comment: yes i have that variable

Comment: sorry was a typo, in mean in and not us. Anyway verify `username` is not really null and has a value. could you show us how you fill the variable?

Comment: okay i have edited it to make things clearly

Comment: [Use the debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sc65sadd.aspx), Luke!

Comment: You create a `Form3`, pass it the value, and then promptly ignore it.  How do you expect that value to get to `Form2`, which is the only one to display a `Form3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you still need to go to form 2 if you want to directly pass the value to form3? Anyway you can do it this way...

form1:

```
     private void LoginBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     username = txtUsername.Text;


     Form2 frm = new Form2(username);
     frm.Show();
     this.Hide
     }
```

form2:

```
    string Name;
    public Form2(string CName)
            {

                InitializeComponent();
                Name= Cname;
            }

   private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
        Form3 form = new Form3(Name);
        form.Show();
        this.Close();
   }
```

form3:

```
    string Name;
    public Form3(string CName)
            {

                InitializeComponent();
                Name= Cname;
            }

    private void frmTicketandCottages_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(Name); 
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

it's too simple:
in `Button_Click` you don't pass `Name`

```
Form3 form = new Form3();
```

pass `Username` to *Form2* by Declare

```
 public string username
```

or in Constructor like Form3:

```
public string Name;
    public Form2(string CName)
            {

                InitializeComponent();
                Name= Cname;
            }
```

and then

```
  public string username = string.Empty;

     private void LoginBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
             username = txtUsername.Text;
             Form3 form  = new Form3(username);

             Form2 frm = new Form2(username);
             frm.Show();
             this.Hide
    }
```

you must pass the `Name` like this:

```
 Form3 form  = new Form3(username);
```