# How to pass value from first form to the third form on c#?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, data-binding, textbox

So I have this Login form with username textbox, password textbox, and a button like what typical Login form looks like for my **c# Windows Form Application** that I'm currently developing.

Once login is successful, the user will be directed to the second form, which is basically like a menu prompting a user to choose which form he/she wants to go to next, for instance, adding, updating, delete product info, and some sorts. And then, there's this **Transaction form**.

What I'm trying to do is to fill out one of the **textbox** in **Transaction form** with the **value(username)** that was **filled in** on the **Login form**.

**How can I do that?**

Comment: At login time (in login form), store the value in a static variable somewhere in a class within your project! you will be able to retrieve it anywhere, it is good to use properties for storing/retrieving such values!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559770/send-values-from-one-form-to-another-form

Comment: maybe this could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26083803/how-to-pass-form1-value-to-form3-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

To do this you can Overload the form constructor and pass the value from first form to second form by form constructor.

```
public frmSecondForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}



public frmSecondForm(string txtUserName,string txtPassword)
{
   InitializeComponent();

   userName=txtUserName;

   password=txtPassword;
}
```

then in the first form call the second form by overloaded constructor like this:

```
frmSecondForm f=new frmSecondForm(un,pa);
f.ShowDialog();
```